# Using variables on a mod_rewrite html page?

Tags: mod-rewrite, cross-browser, seo

I have a website that is rewritten so URLs are .html 
eg: mysite.com/about-us.html

I'm going to add a search feature in which could have a number of different criteria. So my question.... I know the following would work ok as I tried it:
mysite.com/search.html?var1=xxx&var3=xxx

Is there any reason why I should do this as html pages generally wouldn't have variables? I will test, but would there be any browser issues (old browser perhaps)? Any SEO disadvantages?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course ".html"-files can contain variables.
It is not dependent of the Browser but the Server Configuration.
The Server respectively the php-parser must adjusted to parse .html files.

But I don't think that ".html" ending are relevant for google see:

https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/5333/url-rewrite-should-i-write-a-fake-file-suffix-html-or-something-more-realis)